# Read private variables class members

Tags: c++, class, c++11, private

I'm new to c++ and I need to read from private class members of a class in a method that's in a different class, for example:

```
class a{
private:
int x;

}

class b{
void foo();
}

void b::foo(){
//here I want to read from x that's in a
}
```

Do I have to set up a function in `class a` like `int readx(){return x);)` or `a readclass(){return *this);}`? Is there another way?

Comment: you can use a friend function that can access x.

Comment: You should consider it is probably declared private for a reason.

Comment: @NeilKirk: right, e.g. if the class' designer had in mind to be able to possibly extend it later for use in a multi-threaded environment, where unaudited state access is a game killer.

Comment: @NeilKirk well I read in several places that all class variables should be private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The private section of a class has the objective of 'hiding' the way you handle the data, providing a streamlined way of accesing said data with public methods.
The advantage of using a public method to change the value of private members is that you can, for example, allow values only between 0 and 10 for 'x'.

In your case, you should think about what does 'x' represent in your first class, and if it makes sense for the second class to access it directly and without any control or special consideration. If this is the case, it should probably be a public value. In the other case, you will need to make a public method to read it, like your readx example.
If only 'b' has the privilege to access 'x' directly, you can also define a friend function, like someone already said.

Note that returnig a pointer to the instance wouldn't allow access to private members of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use friend class or function, but it is a bad idea to use private members of methods (tests are only reasonable excuse for that). Better to use public methods for that or redesign your code if you couldn't avoid usage of private members.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a friend function that can access x in foo.

[Reference](http://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/friend-function-class)

Comment: You should post more than this because the link may disappear in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no accessor to this data member in class a then you should declare the member function of class b as a friend function of class a.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
public:    
    void foo() const;
};

class A
{
public:
    A( int x ) : x( x ){}
private:    
    friend void B::foo() const;
    int x;
};

void B::foo() const
{
    A a { 10 };
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    B().foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `: x( x ){}` What is that?

Comment: @kuhaku It is so-called ctor initialization. Expression x( x ) after colon initializes data member x with the value of parameter x.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a `friend` function or class would grant read and write access to a's x to that function or class, a

```
class a {
public:
   const int& readx() const { return x; }
private:
   int x 
};
```

or, if you like that semantics better

```
class a {
public:
   const int& x() const { return x_; }
private:
   int x_; 
};
```

grants read access only, but to every client.

Comment: Why the const before after the function's name?

Comment: @kuhaku the first `const` to ensure readonly access (mind it's a ref, not  a value that is returned), and the second to allow calling it on `const a` instances. Aside of that one general rule of thumb in C++ (and C) is the idiom **`const as const can`** - what is not intended to need be mutable, should always also be declared as such - `const` that is.